# How to deal with different lengths of dependent variables for Multiple Multivariate regression?

Tags: r, regression

So this question is probably part statistics and part r studio related.
I want to run a Multiple Multivariate Regression with 13 dependent variables and 4 predictors.
The 13 variables are scales from 1-6, which I coded as a numeric variable.
Unfortunately, some of these variables don't show the full range, therefore have different lengths.

Question 1: I believe I read somewhere, that this poses a problem for the calculations and should therefore be addressed. Is that true for this type of code?

Question 2: If it does pose a problem in interpreting results, how can I fix this? Is it enough to standardize the dependent variables maybe? How do I do this in R though?

(As an example I am using the Quartet data set from R, just rounding each variable)

```
Quartet

Quartet$y1 <- round(Quartet$y1, 0)
Quartet$y2 <- round(Quartet$y2, 0)
Quartet$y3 <- round(Quartet$y3, 0)
Quartet$y4 <- round(Quartet$y4, 0)


summary(Quartet)

M <- lm(cbind(y3, y4) ~ x + x4, data = Quartet)

summary(M)
```

Keep in mind, this code runs smoothly without an error, that isn't the issue.
I would need to do extra diagnostic checking at this point. But I don't know just in how far the results are rigged just by having different ranges for y3 (5-12) and y4 (5-13).

Thank you!

Comment: I votes to move this to CrossValidated.  The R part of the answer about standardizing you could do with the `scale()` function.  Let's say you had a data frame called `dat` with variables `y1`-`y13`, you could do the following with `dplyr`: `dat %>% mutate(across(y1:y13, ~c(scale(.x))))` that would standardize all of the variables.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know about CrossValidated! I'll post my question there, thank you.
For the code you gave: After doing that, I would just create the model with lm like usual?

Comment: Yes, assuming someone doesn't give you a different suggestion.  Nothing comes to my mind about why this would be a bad idea, but I'm sure lots of people know more about multivariate regression models than I do.

Comment: Thanks @DaveArmstrong for migrating this here. I don't see any problems with the different ranges of the LHS variables here. Maybe the OP could explicate more why she thinks it is a problem? (Please do so by editing the text of the question; do not reply in the comments below, comments do not always show in their entirety.)